# Redirecting the user to a page in a different directory in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

I am working on ASP.NET that has 2 folders/directories named `Test1` and `Test2`.

How can I redirect the user from Test1 to Test2?

I get a 404 error with this code:

```
if (!User.IsInRole("admin")){
    Response.Redirect("../Test2/Login.asxp");
}
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with SQL, Scripts, or .MDF databases?

Comment: The question title is entirely misleading, please rephrase your title in order to draw people with appropriate experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could it be:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Test2/Login.aspx");
```

you have asxp

There are many other things it could be most of which fall in to the typos category.  What is the resulting URL that is in the address bar of your browser when you get a 404 page?  Have you saved the Login.aspx page that resides in Test2?

Comment: If the folder "Test2" isn't in the root of the web app, then the ../ is the correct syntax